# JAXB - Send XML with namespace to REST controller in SpringBoot

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, namespaces, jaxb

I am POSTing an xml to my springboot application and receiving it into a Pojo Jaxb and returning a response . I am able to do this successfully , however if i pass xml with namespace i am getting response code as 406 and response body as no content . I tried various ways to add namespace in my Pojo and even tried adding it in package-info but i am unable to find a way to get it working , Please advice . Below is the working example with a simple xml without namespace

Pojo Employee.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Employee")
public class Employee {  
    private int id;  
    private String name;  
    private float salary;  

    public Employee() {}  
    public Employee(int id, String name, float salary) {  
        super();  
        this.id = id;  
        this.name = name;  
        this.salary = salary;  
    }  
    @XmlAttribute  
    public int getId() {  
        return id;  
    }  
    public void setId(int id) {  
        this.id = id;  
    }  
    @XmlElement  //(namespace="http://www.example.org/property")
    public String getName() {  
        return name;  
    }  
    public void setName(String name) {  
        this.name = name;  
    }  
    @XmlElement  
    public float getSalary() {  
        return salary;  
    }  
    public void setSalary(float salary) {  
         this.salary = salary;  
    }  
}
```

Below is my Controller method which is getting values from the xml via POJO

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/myURL" }, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/xml" })
public ResponseEntity<?> postMethodXMLreturnXML(@RequestBody Employee list) {  
    try {
        Employee FirstValue=list;
        System.out.println("SOP : post Method started . Name " + FirstValue.getName());         
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(Employee , HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return (new ResponseEntity<String>(ErrorCodes.SERVER_ERROR.getDescription(),
                HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
    }
}
```

Below is the xml which i post to this and get desired output with valid response code and response message

Input post xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employee>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>myName</name>
  <salary>1.1</salary>
</Employee>
```

But i want now to pass below xml , and when i pass below xml to this code i get response code 406 and no content , Tried adding namespace in pojo and even tried adding code to package info, Please advice 
Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employee>
  <myns:id>1</myns:id>
  <myns:name>myName</myns:name>
  <myns:salary>1.1</myns:salary>
</Employee>
```

Comment: You only use a namespace in the opening tags. The closing tags don't have one.

Comment: Closing also has it , updated ...

Comment: Attach the client code.

Comment: Using swagger to test

Answer (score 1):

The XML uses namespace prefixes, but the namespace itself is not defined in Employee's start tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employee xmlns:myns="http://example/a/b/c">
  <myns:id>1</myns:id>
  <myns:name>myName</myns:name>
  <myns:salary>1.1</myns:salary>
</Employee>
```

Also add the namespace to each XML element.

```
@XmlElement(namespace="http://example/a/b/c")
```

Comment: @paarthbatra how do you send it? Are you using `Content-Type: application/xml` in the header?

Comment: i am posting the xml which you just posted in your answer to the post URL of my spring boot microservice . and in response receive Response code 406 and response body no content and response headers {
  "connection": "close",
  "cache-control": "must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store",
  "server": "unspecified",
  "content-type": null
} . Basically its not able to read the input xml

Comment: Yes .. see in controlled code .  consumes = { "application/xml" }

Comment: @paarthbatra that's an `Accept` header  where the server tells the client what type of content it accepts. I'm referring to a client side `Content-Type` header to tell the server the type of content you're sending along in the body.

Comment: Yes , setting at Client side as well

Comment: @paarthbatra do you have the namespace set for each XML element?

Comment: Just tried that but same result . Below is package-info,java @XmlSchema(
     namespace="http://example/a/b/c", 
     elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
     xmlns={

             @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://example/a/b/c", prefix = "inv")
     }
 )
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

package com.techm.bm.postpaymentMS.POJOs;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;  and this is xml i am passing <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employee xmlns:inv="http://example/a/b/c">
  <inv:id>1</inv:id>
  <inv:name>string</inv:name>
  <inv:salary>1.1</inv:salary>
</Employee>