# How to add namespace in rest XML response?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, rest

We are creating a Spring boot REST service that can support both XML and JSON formats. We are using the same approach described here: [Accepting / returning XML/JSON request and response - Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270660/accepting-returning-xml-json-request-and-response-spring-mvc)

It worked mostly except that we need to have a namespace in the XML response, currently the response xml doesn't have any namespaces. We tried to add the following in the DTO class and also tried to create a "package-info.java". Neither worked. Anyone has suggestions?

*@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.aa.com/bb",
elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, xmlns = {
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix="ns1", namespaceURI="http://www.aa.com/bb")*
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use "JacksonXmlRootElement" (instead of "XmlRootElement")  and "JacksonXmlProperty" (instead of "XmlElement") annotations. Such as:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(namespace="http://www.aa.com/bb", localName="courseName")
public class Course implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String courseName;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace="http://www.aa.com/bb")
    public String getCourseName() { return courseName; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried providing the namespace to the XMLElement or XMLRootElement like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "student", namespace="ns1")
public class Student implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

I haven't tried this in a project, but seems meaningful.
Here is a similar question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46501216/402341

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I did try to add the "namespace="http://www.aa.com/bb" in all the XMLRootElements for each request and response POJO class, but still didn't see the namespace in the XML response. Haven't tried to add that in each XMLElement in the request POJOs yet since there're quite a few out there(it seems to be irrelevant also).

Comment: Looks like using "JacksonXmlRootElement" and "JacksonXmlProperty" annotation is the answer.